# Node async race condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a route in Node that:

1. Accepts a user ID
2. Gets the user from redis
3. Updates a property on the user
4. Saves the user back to redis

As redis uses async methods to get and save, if another request comes in for the same user, I get stale results.

What is the best pattern to make sure the second request doesn't process until the first is finished? Using sync versions of get and set seems wrong as it's locking, although I don't think it will have any noticeable effect in my application.

Comment: Np idea what the best method is, but if you only have one instance of the node script running, a basic array does the job well. Only update if the username isn't in the currentlyUpdating array.

Comment: Just using a boolean value to check if updating would work.  But if you have lots of places were this happens, a better approach might be to use a queue.  Something like -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-queue might help, of course make sure concurrency is set to 1, to avoid the issue you mention.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't just check a boolean as I needed to queue up the requests and not just dismiss them. You pointed me in the right direction and I used [async-lock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-lock) in the end which seems to be doing the job well.